# Serial flash programmer, how to update only part of the data in SPI Flash

Tags: microcontroller, spi, serial, flash, programmer

I have SP8-A serial flash programmer and Winbond 25Q32BVSIG chip. I want to update only specific part of the data in SPI Flash, not touching the rest data on the chip. The programmer Manual does not specify anything about that. For example, only to update the data in the specific area of memory (assigned region), with offset 0x00010000 and size 0x00010000.
I can't figure out is that possible, and, if yes, how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Use "Ignore". HEX file has address and size info. All those combined, you can locate the Hex content anywhere without touching the rest.

Comment: Whatever you try, at least read the whole flash contents first into a file. Preferably twice, and compare that the contents match. Then you can try different things. Like program the chip partially, or make a copy of original dump file and modify it, so you can write full contents back.

Comment: @jay What I should specify on 'File Start' and 'Buffer Start' fields in my case: offset `0x00010000` in the 'Buffer Start' and `0` in the 'File Start'?

Comment: That dialog suggests; the flash has been erased, programmed, and "offset 0x00010000 and size 0x00010000" are left blank, per your description. You can decode [intel hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX)and tell the offset/address and the size, if you did not set it. "File Start" comes from that address in the hex, could be zero.Buffer start is 0x00010000. You may not have option to force the size, and the utility takes the hex to the end. You may generate appropriate hex, or edit the hex directly. If you were compiling to get the hex, we can discuss that as well.

Comment: That dialogue just default picture from manual. The file is .bin format (partition).